# Rails 3: how to change form with select box?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that needs to be changed based on the different choices in a select box. The select box I need has the following options:
Pay & Gifts (both fields are shown),
Pay Only (only the pay field is shown),
Gifts Only (only the gift field is shown).

This involves 2 attributes, :pay and :gifts. Is there a way to have one f.collection select box for both attributes? I know I'll probably have to use jquery to show and hide the form fields, and the fields are mandatory (validates_presence_of) based on the selection...any suggestions on how to do this?

**_rewards_step.html.erb**

```
<h2>rewards</h2>

  <p>
<%= f.collection_select :pay, Upload::REWARDS, :to_s, :to_s %>
  </p>
  <p id="payfields">
    <%= f.label :pay %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :pay %>
  </p>
  <p id="giftsfields">
    <%= f.label :gifts %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :gifts %>
  </p>
```

**upload.rb**

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :pay, :gifts
attr_writer :current_step

validates_presence_of :pay, :if => lambda { |u| u.current_step == "rewards" }
validates_presence_of :gifts, :if => lambda { |u| u.current_step == "rewards" }

REWARDS = ['Pay & Gifts', 'Pay Only', 'Gifts Only']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the pay field for both select and input as a text. It probably won't be good, I suggest you to create an additional field for the choice to take. It is enough if it is only a virtual attribute, not necessary to store it in the databas, but you will need it for the validation.

The jQuery part to hide the fields:

```
$("#rewards").change(function(){
  if ($("#rewards").val()=="Pay Only") {$("#gift_field").hide(); $("#pay_field").show(); }
  if ($("#rewards").val()=="Gift Only") {$("#gift_field").show(); $("#pay_field").hide(); }
  if ($("#rewards").val()=="Pay & Gift") {$("#gift_field").show(); $("#pay_field").show(); }
})
```

Of course, you need to adjust the ids and values to your code.

The validation part can be tricked with the `:if`

```
attr_accessor :reward_type
validates_presence_of :pay, :if => lambda { |u| u.current_step == "rewards" && reward_type != "Gift Only" }
validates_presence_of :gifts, :if => lambda { |u| u.current_step == "rewards" && reward_type != "Pay Only" }
```

This is just a skeleton of the solution, think about it.

Comment: thanks for the info...I've been having a problem assigning an id to the select box. this is what I currently have: <%= f.collection_select :reward_type, Upload::REWARDS, :to_s, :to_s, :id => "rewards" %>. Is there anything wrong with this line?

Comment: Yes, there is, your id used as an option for the select, not as an HTML option. Try this: `<%= f.collection_select :reward_type, Upload::REWARDS, :to_s, :to_s, {}, {:id => "rewards"} %>`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, generally speaking, you are right, you will have to use javascript to update the DOM based on the choice in the select box. You can bind to the 'change' event of the select box itself. Something like:

```
$('select#my_select_box_id').change(function(){ 
  //take a decision based on $(this).val()
  $('p#giftsfield').show()  //or hide based on what you want
})
```

But I'm not sure if your code will work like this. You are giving your select box the name 'pay' and down below there's a text field with the same name. I think the second attribute will overwrite the first one. Furthermore your conditional validations take the same lambda as the condition. So both attributes will be validated when that condition is met. But of course I don't know the example in full :-).

Comment: would you recommend creating a separate attribute for the select box?

Comment: Definitely. The thing below looks good. Although I think there is no need to pass in that :to_s symbol to collection_select.